# Does paypal send a notification when someone cancels their preapproved payment?

Tags: notifications, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

If a user approves a preapproval payment and then goes to paypal and cancels their preapproved payment, does paypal send any kind of notification to my application to let me know that it has been canceled?

Here is some documentation on the matter: [Paypal Preapproval API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PayPal sends an IPN message in response to a payment, a refund,
>   creation of a preapproval, and cancellation of a preapproval. Your IPN
>   message handler must be set up in the way described in the Instant
>   Payment Notification Guide.

[Source](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIPN/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason an IPN isn't sent when someone cancels a Pay request (ie: with pay key)?